# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_leaflet_events')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using `leaflet v1.8.0` and `react-leaflet v4.0.1` in my **Next.js** app. I have a map container component and marker group components inside it. Previously it was running fine but after some database changes in the backend and fixing the frontend accordingly, I started getting error like this whenever I try to load the page with the map container component.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_leaflet_events')

Call Stack
addOne
node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.esm.js (2789:0)
on
node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.esm.js (2718:0)
NewClass._addFocusListenersOnLayer
node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.esm.js (10894:0)
NewClass._addFocusListeners
node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.esm.js (10887:0)
NewClass.fire
node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.esm.js (599:0)
NewClass._layerAdd
node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.esm.js (6827:0)
NewClass.whenReady
node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.esm.js (4583:0)
```

I have a map container component **CameraSitesMap.js** like this:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, ZoomControl } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.css'
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility'
import 'leaflet-area-select'
    ...    
    return (
            <div css={styles.mapContainer}>
              {isLoading ? (
                <div css={styles.loader}>
                  <Spinner />
                </div>
              ) : (
                <MapContainer
                  preferCanvas={true}
                  bounds={mapBounds}
                  zoomControl={false}
                  scrollWheelZoom={false}
                  doubleClickZoom={false}
                  boxZoom={false}
                  style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
                  attributionControl={false}
                >
                  <ZoomControl position="bottomleft" />
                  {cameraView || isExploreMode() ? (
                    <AreaSelector setSelectionArea={setSelectionArea} />
                  ) : null}
                  <TileLayer
                    attribution='<img src="https://www.onemap.gov.sg/docs/maps/images/oneMap64-01.png" style="height:20px;width:20px;"/> OneMap | Map data &copy; contributors, <a href="http://SLA.gov.sg">Singapore Land Authority</a>'
                    url="https://maps-{s}.onemap.sg/v3/Default/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                  />
                  {!isExploreMode() ? (
                    !cameraView ? (
                      <SiteLocations />
                    ) : (
                      <CameraLocations />
                    )
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <SiteLocations />
                      <CameraLocations />
                    </>
                  )}
                </MapContainer>
              )}
            </div>
          )
```

which basically renders a map into the page component with some view toggling logic for different marker groups: `<SiteLocations />` and `<CameraLocations />`.

And this is what the **SiteLocations.js** looks like:

```
import { Circle, Tooltip, useMap } from 'react-leaflet'
...
const SiteLocations = () => {
  const map = useMap()
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    setMap(map)  // just storing instance in zustand store for another component
  }, [])

  const processedSitesData = isExploreMode() ? exploringSite : allSites;

  return (
    <>
      {processedSitesData?.map((site) => {
        const id = site?.id
        const { name } = site?.attributes
        const { lat, lng, area } = site?.attributes
        const position = [lat, lng]

        // console.log(id, name, lat, lng, area) 
        // none of these logs are undefined
        return (
          <Circle
            center={position}
            radius={area}
            weight={1}
            color="blue"
            key={id}
            css={styles.circleMarker}
            eventHandlers={{
              click: () => !isExploreMode() && setExploreSite(site),
            }}
          >
            {!isExploreMode() && (
              <Tooltip>This is a placeholder.</Tooltip>  // The error doesn't occur and the circle is correctly rendered if I replace this line with <></>.
            )}
          </Circle>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

If I remove the Tooltip, the error is gone and the Circle itself renders perfectly. **Previously before the database changes, this was working fine.** So I tried logging the data used in the component, but they all have correct values and are not undefined. I have tried removing node_modules and reinstalling with yarn in case the package wasn't installed properly. I have also tried Clear Site Data in browser. The error still happens if I add Tooltip. Please help.

Comment: Might be there is an issue with `Tooltip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, everyone. Thanks for your time.

**I had to update my `react-leaflet` and `leaflet` package versions.** It seems to be a bug in the Leaflet library itself and solved in `leaflet v1.9.2` according to the release notes: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/releases